# Whats the best way to clear / empty Apache log files periodically

Tags: cron, logs, apache-httpd, webserver, lubuntu

I am running Apache server on lubuntu linux, Since there are plenty of applications ruining on the web server with 10+ users accessing the server regularly, the server logs [access & error logs] gets piled up to huge size.

I cannot turn off them since we might need to monitor them for security as well as we use the logs for debugging.

Is there a way we can auto clear them every weekend or so ? during the process its vital that Apache should keep running. I am aware of the permission issues thats why I seek help here from the Linux veterans.

Comment: This is a solved problem with logrotate, which is already installed on Ubuntu. IIRC the default logrotate settings are weekly rotation. Hmm. According to `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2`, it is fortnightly for apache.

Comment: Look into `logrotate`.

Comment: This should be automatically happening already. How far back do you have apache logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, `logrotate` does this for you already. Just install (if it's not already installed) and enable it. Trying to do this with a custom cron job as @Dave mentions, while perhaps functional, is really not a good idea for your long-term sanity.

Comment: Log-rotate was not installed for some reason, Just installed and enabled it. I wonder why that was not installed along side Apache? Will monitor this for a week. Hopefully this should work fine

Comment: It's always been installed by default on my machines, but I'm not all to picky about paring down initial packages. It is not a dependency of or dependent on Apache, so there's no built-in association between the two.

Comment: I guess this occurs when there are more than one admin operator, sadly I was not present while the machine was initially configured. Anyways Good to learn stuffs